# Project Euler #402

Tags: number-theory

I'm surprised at the sheer number of questions from PE in here.
Well I don't want a solution, but I would like some sort of a hint in the right direction with [problem 402](http://projecteuler.net/problem=402).

I haven't been able to find a closed form solution for S(N). This is about as far as I got [which is quite a loop](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/243872/need-help-simplifying-an-equation).

Now I know a couple more things like that Fib(N) mod 1e9 is periodic. Look at [Pisano Periods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pisano_period) and S(N) has a period as well.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty easy to figure out how S(n) behaves once you fully understand M(a, b, c). So my suggestion is if you're looking for a closed form expression for S(n), find one for M(a, b, c) first.

Caveat: I figured out a good function for S(n) days ago. Once I did, I said to myself, "great, I got the hard part done." I was very wrong. I am having a huge amount of trouble wrapping my head around solving the rest of the problem.